Book read between 2015 and 2018 about a girl who is kept alone and her memory keeps being wiped after meeting a boy
This is girl is kept in isolation and this boy keeps meeting with her and they fall in love. The people in charge of her keep wiping her memory though.
She ends up running away with him and the people in that time period think she’s a witch because she saves a child from a flipped over carriage. She ends up having to be with another person that is genetically modified later.
She was kept in isolation and modified by the government to mate with another modified man to create perfect humans, I think. There is even a part where we watches an old video when he’s trying to save her of them breaking her leg and it healing itself during an experiment.

Is this a time travel story?
